# How do I connect to and exchange 2010 server using technologies other than .Net?

Tags: java, php, interop, exchange-server

I need to access exchange 2010 calendaring services from a thunderbird plugin. The web services are missing their "services", apparently they are all kept in ExchangeServiceBinding class. Any ideas on how to connect to these services using anything other than .Net? We have skills in python, php, java and can learn a few more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I have only used Active Directory and Email Service.
The following link might help to read calender service using Java:

http://code.google.com/p/exchange-calendar/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/ws/ExchangeCalendarRetriever.java?r=2

Comment: Perfect thanks, I figured most of that out during the day. I'm now getting an "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" caused my the NTLM authentication. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: This seems more like program error not the interface. Could you please paste the whole StackTrace?

Answer (score 1):

DavMail (<http://DavMail.SourceForge.net>) would be another option.